# How to get the row and column index in ForEach loop of a 2D array in swiftUI?

Tags: arrays, swiftui, foreach, 2d

I would like to get the row and column index in ForEach loop of a 2D array in swiftUI.

```
let array = [
    
    ["1", "2", "3"],
    ["4", "5", "6"],
    ["7", "8", "9"]
    
]
```

ForEach(array, id: .self) { row in

```
    ForEach(row, id: \.self) { element in

// How to get the index i and j for row and column of a 2D array in swiftUI ???

    }
```

}

Comment: did any of the answers worked or you?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an array of `[String]` you must have 2 `ForEach`:

```
ForEach(Array(row.enumerated()), id:\.self) { i, array in
    ForEach(Array(array.enumerated()), id: \.self) { j, element in
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this, `...to get the index i and j for row and column of a 2D array...`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let array = [["1", "2", "3"],["4", "5", "6"],["7", "8", "9"]]
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(array.indices, id: \.self) { i in
            ForEach(array[i].indices, id: \.self) { j in
                Text(array[i][j])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to set Data if data is coming from API?

Comment: don't understand your comment/question here. Explain what you want to achieve and show some code example, possibly in a separate question on stack overflow.